# How to make an automatic reminder with jobs with TSQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there a way to make an automatic reminder via email when those dates comes and send the rows info from the same table, for example:

In the following table we have to columns with different dates, DUEDATE need to be a reminder from expedition and EXPDV is another reminder 15 day before DUEDATE, So when one of those dates from any row comes I want to make to send and automatic Reminder via email with the row info (PSLOT,PSQRCV,ETC) From that table , any ideas?

[image: DATES For reminders]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I detect a date on a column from a table and then send me a reminder or a notification of that date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59110684/how-can-i-detect-a-date-on-a-column-from-a-table-and-then-send-me-a-reminder-or). Tip: Reasons not to use images are [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/92546). What have you tried? What research have you done?

Comment: Oh, sorry for that...
Just needed an idea but will take that as advice:)

Answer (score 0):

```
    USE [database_name]
    GO

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @count INT = 
        (
            SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.TableName
            WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, EXPDV, DUEDATE) = 15  
        )


    IF @count > 0
    BEGIN           
        DECLARE   @html     NVARCHAR(max) 
                , @subject  NVARCHAR(max) = 'Your email subject here'
                , @email    NVARCHAR(255)
                , @PSLOT    NVARCHAR(255)
                , @PSQRCV   NVARCHAR(255)
                , @ETC      NVARCHAR(255)

        DECLARE send_remider CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT email, PSLOT,PSQRCV,ETC FROM dbo.TableName
        WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, EXPDV, DUEDATE) = 15 

        OPEN send_remider

        FETCH NEXT FROM send_remider INTO @email, @PSLOT, @PSLOT, @ETC

        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

        BEGIN

            SET @html = 'Your message body text here....' + @PSLOT, @PSQRCV, @ETC


            EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
                  @profile_name = 'profile_name'    
                , @recipients = @email              
                , @subject = @subject
                , @body = @html
                , @body_format = 'HTML'


        FETCH NEXT FROM send_remider INTO @email, @PSLOT, @PSLOT, @ETC

        END
        CLOSE send_remider
        DEALLOCATE send_remider
        GO
```

You can create a job and run this cursor. I haven't tested it. So, you should make yourself a recipient during testing.

Comment: Looks great! in fact I use cursor as well.
Let me try it, thank you Israel!

Comment: Hi there! 
For example, The email column will be remove from that table but I have another table with valid emails, I need to use Inner join to select the emails from the other table?

Comment: Yes, you should inner join. If it helps, mark as answered.

Comment: About this line
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, EXPDV, DUEDATE) = 15 
The EXPDV already has the subtract of 15 days, you use it for that reason? or why?

Comment: If you have a derived column that gets updated every day to show you the difference in days between EXPDV and DUEDATE you can use it.